# while import xlrd and xlwt in python getting error message

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to import xlrd and xlwt module in python in windows and getting following error message please suggest how to resolve it.

While importing xlrd

```
import xlrd

Traceback <most recent call lst>:
File "<stdin>", line 1,in <module>
File "c:\Python33\lib\site-package\xlrd\__init__.py", line 3, in <module> from info import __Version__
ImportError : No module named 'info'
```

While importing xlwt

```
import xlwt


Traceback <most recent call lst>:
File "<stdin>", line 1,in <module>
File "c:\Python33\lib\site-package\xlwt\__init__.py", line 10, in <module> from    Workbook import Workbook
ImportError : No module named 'Workbook'
```

Thanks,
Niraj

Comment: how did u install xlrd and xlwt.is it using PIP?

Comment: Looks like they're trying to do implicit relative imports. Are you sure you installed a version that supports Python 3?

Comment: If you are working with Python 3 you must install the module `future` and `xlwt-future` of Charmers http://python-future.org/what_else.html  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt-future

Comment: @ sundar nataraj Сундар : I have download as .exe
For xlwt : xlwt-0.7.2.win32.exe
For xlrd : xlrd-0.7.9.win32.exe

Comment: Downloaded xlwt and xlrd module are working with python 2.7 , That error was comming for Python 3. Thanks Trimax will try that module in Python 3